# generating product 'suggestions' for users based on relative information from other users

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with three tables set up like this:

*Users*: username, user_id
*Products*: product_name, product_id
*User_Products*: product_id, user_id, relation_level

These are all pretty straight forward, when a user clicks to 'like' a product, it asks how much they like it (rated 1-5) and stores that information in the User_Products table, storing the product_id from the Products table, user_id from the Users table and relation_level based on how much they like the product.

What I want to do is generate suggestions for products the user might like, based on products the user likes and how much they like the products, getting users who like similar products and finding products the user doesn't already know about, based on the number of people who like them and the level they like them.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like the most classic and canonical of recommender engine problems. [Apache Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org) has a complete recommender engine framework, including a simple non-distributed, non-Hadoop version that will be easy to experiment with.

In particular, you will just want to plug in one of the JDBC-based `DataModel` implementations to start in order to read your data. The rest is a few lines of code.

Now, I know you said PHP. Mahout is Java. But you can look at setting this up as a web service that your PHP could access.

Comment: I would rather not use a Java plugin as I have absolutely no experience with Java at all and I might have a problem getting my head around it, however, would it be possible to re-write it into PHP, or use CodeIgniter to do a similar thing with their classes and database driver?

The main thing I am concerned about is PHP load, if I am dealing with a few hundred members it should be ok but if it ends up with a lot more, it could be problematic so I am also thinking about scalability too!

Comment: You could port just the bits you want to PHP without a great deal of trouble; it's still probably thousands of lines of code. I agree that PHP is probably not going to be suitable for more than small data sets.